# DOCX4J - Replace paragraphs

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a template which I need to change some values. I'm using `VariablePrepare.prepare()` and `mainDocumentPartObject.variableReplace(hashMap)` to do it.

But now I have to create whole paragraph dynamically and add to a certain position.

I have my `P` dynamically created. How can I place it in a position or replace for an existing paragraph? I have a method that already read all paragraphs from document and I can find where I need to replace, if is the case:

```
private static void addParagraph(List<Object> paragraphs, P paragraphToAdd) {

    for (Object paragraph : paragraphs) {
        if (paragraph instanceof P) {
            for (Object run : ((P) paragraph).getContent()) {
                if (run instanceof R) {
                    for (Object item : ((R) run).getContent()) {
                        JAXBElement<?> element = ((JAXBElement<?>) item);
                        if (element.getDeclaredType().getName().equals("org.docx4j.wml.Text")) {
                            if (((Text)element.getValue()).getValue().equals("MY_VARIABLE")) {
                                //EDIT
                                ((P) paragraph).getContent().removeAll(((P) paragraph).getContent());
                                ((P) paragraph).getContent().addAll(paragraphToAdd.getContent());
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I have editted the code. It replaces, but without all the formats and styles I had set before.

Comment: If you want formatting, you'll have to set it in the P you are inserting.  You can generate relevant code from a sample docx using the docx4j helper Word AddIn, or webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html  or just copy it from from an existing p with newP.setPpr(oldP.getPpr())

Comment: @JasonPlutext thank you for your answer! Setting Ppr work just fine! But still some words with special characters (accents), like ("é", "ç") are a bit odd.
Is there any way to fix it? Setting encoding or something?

Comment: Actually for those special characters it is changed automatically the font family and size. I have set Arial and 24 and it comes with default Times New Roman

Comment: setHAnsi; see for example https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/FontHandler.java#L62

Comment: Thank you so much @JasonPlutext!